# Keras ConvLSTM Optimization for Results and Memory Management

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have images I'm using to predict a value (linear activation) and I'm relatively new to using neural networks.  The images I have include a lot of detail and are high-ish resolution, but as they're satellite images, this is problematic due to massive size (8090, 12894).  My target is a scalar between 0 & 1.

My goal is to use sequencing (RNN through ConvLSTM) and convolution to better predict values.

My steps are as follows:

1. Function loads images into memory and processes them along the way, returns array
2. Generator reads from the above array and feeds to the model, this is currently not necessary but if I can get the model small enough to run on GPU it will be.
3. Model reads from the array through the generator.

I would like help optimizing the model for my goal, shrinking the model size in memory but increasing the accuracy.

Below are relevant parts of my code:

```
def build_model(frames=seq_len, channels=3, pixels_x=w, pixels_y=h, kernel_sizing=kernel_sizing):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(
        ConvLSTM2D(filters=16
                   , kernel_size=kernel_sizing
                   , strides = 3
                   , data_format='channels_last'
                   , return_sequences = False
                   , activation='relu', input_shape=(frames, pixels_x, pixels_y, channels))
                )
    model.add(
        Conv2D(filters=16
                   , kernel_size=(3,3)
                   , activation='relu')
                )
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
    
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.001)
    
    model.compile(    
        loss = "mse",
        optimizer = optimizer,
        metrics=['mae', 'mse'])
    
    return model
```

Notes:

1. Generally I have to resize to about .1 which makes me lose the detail
2. I've tried kernel_sizing of (3,3) and (11,11) & want more filters but this uses significant amounts of memory
3. I could play with strides further depending on the size of kernels, this is where I wonder if I could "shrink" the size of the model in memory
4. Because my target value is a number between 0 & 1, do I need to use MAE instead of MSE as the MSE could get strange due to very small errors?
5. Do I need a larger dense layer after the flatten?  How do I prevent this from being gigantic?
6. I believe that many of my memory issues are caused by the images being so big, but how do I manage this and maintain my level of detail?
7. (From above) Do I need to cut out chunks of my images and increase the size of my data sets using the target variables for the chunks?  If so, how would this work for testing new images from actual predictive sets?

Edit:
model.summary():
[image]

Comment: How many parameters does your model.summary() output? The first thing I would start at is to increase the strides by a factor of 2?

Comment: Edit for adding model.summary()

Comment: You should be able to add more convolutional layers with smaller kernel sizes and have 16-64 filters each. This will increase your depth but will make your fully connected layers significantly smaller. The depth should also improve your accuracy. I'm not sure what the impact would be on #params but it *may* actually lower it.

Comment: You can also make your model invariable to image size, then train on progressively larger images, starting from a .1 scale, for example, then moving up to full scale images. This way, you should be able to get a significantly more effective model than just trying to train on full scale if you have limitations on computation

Comment: How do I go about making it invariable to image sizes?  The model seems to always want an input shape yeah?  If you could provide parameters, model type, etc I can research this.

Comment: Your choice of a linear activation does not make much sense to me. Because you have selected linear, your network will have the capability (and almost certainly will do this) to produce values greater than 1 or less than 0. Your model will probably perform significantly better with a sigmoidal function paired with binary cross-entropy

Comment: I believe fully convolutional networks can do the trick @krewsayder though I can't remember all the specifics, Conv1D layers are involved last time I checked.

Comment: [Here](https://towardsdatascience.com/implementing-a-fully-convolutional-network-fcn-in-tensorflow-2-3c46fb61de3b#2d04)'s a link to an article I found that describes using 1x1 convolutional layers instead of dense layers. I didn't read the whole thing but it might be applicable

Comment: I'm a little confused by the binary cross entropy and sigmoid.  I am seeing how the sigmoid produces a probability (0 to 1) but how is the binary cross entropy deployed in a manner that will help me produce results here?  I've used it for binary classification but this certainly isn't that.

Answer (score 2):

On a broad note, here are some great suggestions to improve the optimization of your model so you avoid the dreaded “ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor” :

- Use larger strides in your Conv2D layers
- Decrease the number of neurons in your Dense, Conv2D layers
- Use a smaller batch_size (or increase steps_per_epoch)
- Use grayscale images (there will be one channel instead of three)
- Reduce the number of layers
- Use more MaxPooling2D layers, and increase their pool size
- Reduce the size your images (you can use PIL or cv2 for that)
- Apply dropout
- Use smaller float precision, namely np.float16 rather than np.float32 (last resort)
- If you're using a pre-trained model, freeze the first layers

Hope that helps